# NSNetworkManager.ResolveListener messages Android

Tags: android

Can somebody explain the error messages that can be passed into the callbacks i.e.

```
public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode)
```

I've seen error code 3 before but have no idea what it means. The documentation seems flakey at best...

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same question and got the answer from NsdManager sources:

```
/**
 * Failures are passed with {@link RegistrationListener#onRegistrationFailed},
 * {@link RegistrationListener#onUnregistrationFailed},
 * {@link DiscoveryListener#onStartDiscoveryFailed},
 * {@link DiscoveryListener#onStopDiscoveryFailed} or {@link ResolveListener#onResolveFailed}.
 *
 * Indicates that the operation failed due to an internal error.
 */
public static final int FAILURE_INTERNAL_ERROR               = 0;

/**
 * Indicates that the operation failed because it is already active.
 */
public static final int FAILURE_ALREADY_ACTIVE              = 3;

/**
 * Indicates that the operation failed because the maximum outstanding
 * requests from the applications have reached.
 */
public static final int FAILURE_MAX_LIMIT                   = 4;
```

**edited:**

Actually it is mentioned in developer documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html

Answer (score 13):

I worked around this by calling resolveService again. It may fail a couple of times in a row, but eventually resolves.

```
        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service found: "+ serviceInfo);
            if (!serviceInfo.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown service type: " + serviceInfo.getServiceType());
            } else if (serviceInfo.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)){
                Log.d(TAG, "Same machine");
            } else {
                startResolveService(serviceInfo);
            }
        }
```

Rather than call resolveService from within onServiceFound, I call a separate declaration of it:

```
        private void startResolveService(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo){
            NsdManager.ResolveListener newResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {
                @Override
                public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Resolve Failed: " + serviceInfo + "\tError Code: " + errorCode);
                    switch (errorCode) {
                        case NsdManager.FAILURE_ALREADY_ACTIVE:
                            Log.e(TAG, "FAILURE_ALREADY_ACTIVE");
                            // Just try again...
                            startResolveService(serviceInfo);
                            break;
                        case NsdManager.FAILURE_INTERNAL_ERROR:
                            Log.e(TAG, "FAILURE_INTERNAL_ERROR");
                            break;
                        case NsdManager.FAILURE_MAX_LIMIT:
                            Log.e(TAG, "FAILURE_MAX_LIMIT");
                            break;
                    }
                 }

                @Override
                public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Service Resolved: " + serviceInfo);
                    mLocatedServices.add(serviceInfo);
                    reportNewService();
                }
            };
            mNsdManager.resolveService(serviceInfo, newResolveListener);
        }
```

When multiple services are discovered nearly-instantaneously, the first one gets resolved, then you get FAILURE_ALREADY_ACTIVE once or twice more, then the next service gets resolved, and so on.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you very much for sharing it. I do things very similarly, but I started resolving each service with `nsdManager.resolveService(serviceInfo, newResolveListener(){...})` inside the `onServiceFound()` method.

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you.  I just call mNsdManager.resolveService(serviceInfo, mResolveListener); in onResolveFailed() per your tip, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was a bit confused by this also...

Here's what's happening. When you are discovering services, you will often get the exact same service a few times in the same millisecond.

if you log the output from `NsdManager.DiscoveryListener.onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service)` you'll see this.

Now, you probably resolve the service using `mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener)`. Only the first attempt is going to start resolving, the others will give FAILURE_ALREADY_ACTIVE. (At least until the first is completed)

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem two days....and i solve it...

first time i do resolveService(service, mResolveListener);

no callback

and i do again same service, resolveService(service, mResolveListener);

the callback  is error code 3

At least I found ,because my server name is  "III...."

I take  out  double quotes and it's work

hope it's can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that reusing the same listener *with* a semaphore gave the best result.

```
if (semaphore.tryAcquire()) {
    mNsdManager.resolveService(service, resolveListener);
}
```

Using tryAcquire as we do not wan't to block onServiceFound which will lock it completely. With this approach we eventually get all services on the network to show up.